# TypeError: 'module' object is not subscriptable

Tags: json

**Buenas tardes, estoy ejecutando un código de tarea y al ejecutarlo me aparece:**

```
import requests
import json

def consultasigla(sigla):
    headers = {'Accepts':'application/json','X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY':'41f65f66-1d27-4b49-8445-0ca558525739'}
    parametros = {'symbol': sigla}
    res=requests.get("https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/quotes/latest",headers=headers,params=parametros)
    json=res.json()
    if json["data"][sigla]["symbol"] == sigla:
        return True
    else:
        return False

symbol=input("Cuál es la sigla de tu criptomoneda? ")

while not consultasigla(symbol):
    print("Usted ingresó mal la sigla de la criptomoneda. ")
    symbol=input("Cuál es la sigla de tu criptomoneda? ")
```

**el problema se presenta con el else**

```
else:
        print(str(json["data"][symbol]["slug"])+" está cotizado en: "+str(json["data"][symbol]["quote"]["USD"]["price"]))
```

**al ejecutar el código muestra un error**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No puedes crear una variable `json` si has importado un modulo llamado `json`.

El error se produce ya que mas adelante se piensa que esta llamando al modulo `json` pero en realidad esta intentando usar la variable creada. Cambia el nombre de la variable cuando la creas y donde se haga referencia a esta (y no donde se haga referencia al modulo `json`), partiendo en este punto

```
myjson=res.json()
if myjson["data"][sigla]["symbol"] == sigla:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

Comment: Gracias por tan pronta respuesta...Pero soy nuevo en este tema, podrias desarrollar un poco más la idea? ayudarme con un ejemplo? disculpa y gracias

Comment: Tal como en el ejemplo que incluí, renombra la variable `json` a otro nombre , como ejemplo `myjson`. Luego reemplaza los lugares donde exista `json[..]` con `myjson[..]`. Si incluyes en tu pregunta el codigo completo con problemas, puedo sugerirte la edicion mas especifica.

Comment: Igor!!!! Ahora sí entendí, muchas gracias.

Comment: Buena noticia espero que haya servido. Recuerda marcar las respuesta como resuelta, o si te queda alguna duda, consultar lo que necesites.

Comment: como se marca como resuelta?